# has_many belongs_to assocation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

I have two models: `University` and `Market`

A University belongs to a single Market, and a Market can have many universities. For example, An instance of Market like Boston might have University instances like MIT, Harvard, Boston University, etc.

I want to be able to do something like this in console:

`University.first.market.name`

But I get the following error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `market' for #

I can get the market id from `University.first.market_id`, but I can't get the name from `market.name`.

Here is how I have my models set up:

```
class University < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :markets

class Market < ApplicationRecord
has_many :universities
end
```

And here is my schema - I think with the market_id integer column and index correctly implemented (?)

```
  create_table "universities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "full_name"
    t.integer  "market_id"
    t.index ["market_id"], name: "index_universities_on_market_id"
end
```

Here's my markets schema:

```
  create_table "markets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "name"
  end
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: You can also write your migration as  t.belongs_to :market instead of   t.integer  "market_id"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a one-to-many relationship, the "belongs_to" end must be singular, as below:

```
class University < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :market
end

class Market < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :universities
end
```

Let me know if that helps

Comment: I got so used to doing many to many relationships that this totally slipped without me noticing. Thanks Bruno!